# Android In-App purchase blank order id

Tags: android

I am developed an app in which user purchases will registered on the server. And on the server side `OrderId` of `Purchase` class is a primary key.

In android documentation, I have read that order Id will be blank for test purchases. However, my server will not accept blank order id. So I tried this workaround:

```
public static final boolean IS_TEST_PURCHASES = true;

// Before updating to server
if (IS_TEST_PURCHASES && Util.isBlank(purchaseId))
    purchaseId = "Test." + TimeUtils.getCurrentUnixTime();
```

This solved my problem for some time. But, in Beta mode the same problem appeared as I cannot release APK with `IS_TEST_PURCHASES = true`.

I checked the JSON retrned after purchase in which only OrderId is blank and rest of the feilds like signature, token are available. I was thinking if I can make a condition like:

> if `OrderId` is empty and `Signature` or `Token` is not empty, then this
>   purchase is a test purchase and assign some dummy order id to it.

But I am confused whether this condition will cause any future problems.

I need to differentiate real purchase and test purchase so that I can set some dummy OrderId if and only if purchase is made through sandbox testing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can't you change your server to accept blank purchases for your testing purposes?

Comment: No. before google was providing orderid for test purchases also and it was unique every time. So, we have implemented like this very long before. But from BillingApiV3 Google stopped generating orderid for test purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you, but what I did to differentiate between a test purchase and a real purchase was to use both the orderId and the purchaseToken as keys.

If it is a real purchase, there will be an order ID present that follows the pattern of something like GPA.ORDER_ID. If it's a test purchase, you are right there will be no order ID, but there will still be a purchase token that is a long string of random numbers / letters. So I know in my DB if it was a real purchase, the order ID will have GPA.ORDER_ID. If it doesn't follow that pattern, then it was a test purchase.

Comment: Sometimes google gives order id in this format: 1111.1111.11111.11111... I did some research on this pattern and it was being used before 2013 or 2012 and still I receive some of this patterns on my server database. Donno if i can depend order Id's GPA format?

Comment: The format of the order Id is irrelevant to me. Purchase tokens are always > ~100ish characters, so you can easily recognize the difference between a real order Id and a purchase token

Comment: Thnx for helping me out.

Comment: No problem! I know this whole deal was a big hassle when I went through it. Glad to help!